# How to set a boolean variable in the DB using form?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, entity

I have a class named `User`, where I can find properties like `Name`, `email`, ...
Also I have a `Membership` class, related to `User` class and `Community` class, which has a `banish` column.
I want to show the names from `User` in a form (select field) and set the boolean `banish` property to `true` for the user selected. I'm doing the next (`$page['community']` is the `Community` entity).

```
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('banish', 'entity', array(
            'label' => $this->trans("Usuarios a expulsar"),
            'class' => 'Pro\MembershipBundle\Entity\Membership',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($page){
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('membership')                             
                          ->innerjoin('Pro\UserBundle\Entity\User', 'u', 'WITH', 'membership.user = u')
                          ->where( 'membership.community = :community')
                    ->setParameter('community', $page['community']);
                },

        ))
        ->getForm(); 



    if ($this->getRequest()->isMethod('post') && $this->getRequest('form_id') == 'banish') {
        if ($form->bind($this->getRequest())->isValid()) {

            $this->getEntityManager()->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->getRequest()->getUri() . '#preferences');
        }
    }
    $return['banishForm'] = $form->createView();

    //

    return $return;
```

and the view:

```
    <h2 id="banish">{{ "Expulsar miembros" | trans }}</h2>

    <form method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="banish">
        {{ form_widget(banishForm) }}
        <input type="submit" class="btn" value="{{ "Guardar" | trans }}">
    </form>
```

This seems to work fine. But when I select a user and submit the form, the `banish` column from `Membership` selected is not set to `true`. There is something that I'm missing, but I don't know what.

Answer (score 0):

In your user class, do you have cascade setup?  You would need something like the below line on your relation to the membership class (which then links to community class).

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Membership", mappedBy="user", cascade={"all"})
 */
protected $membership
```